# Android: Get 64mp image from Xiaomi Mi 10T

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

I'm trying to get the largest picture from Xiaomi device. When requesting supported resolutions

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(manager.getCameraIdList()[0]);
                StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                Size[] sizes = map.getOutputSizes(ImageReader.class);
```

the highest resolutions I get there is 4624x3472
however when using android camera app, there is 64mp mode for taking picture.
When using this mode, I'm getting image with 6944x9248
How can I get such resolution in my app?

Comment: wxh ?   ......    hxw? 2x?

Comment: If the "android camera app" is a built-in camera app supplied by Xiaomi, it may have access to additional options that are not offered via the Android SDK. Device manufacturers can do what they want.